# Concatenate multiples words each in separate row into one row using R

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a dataframe that has one word per row, but I want to convert it using R to sentences/paragraphs per row based on the value of a the columns spk and id. Here is a the dataframe sample :

```
id  word    spk
123 hi       1
123 how      1
123 are      1
123 you      1
123 good     2
123 thank    2
123 you      2
123 Anything 1
123 I        1
123 can      1
123 do       1
123 nothing  2
123 for      2
123 now      2
789 what     1
789 is       1
789 the      1
789 issue    1
789 there    2
789 is       2
789 no       2
789 issue    2
789 now      2
789 thank    1
789 you      1
789 for      1
789 contacting1
789 us       1
```

**Desired output**

```
id  word                           spk
123 hi how are you                  1
123 good thank you                  2
123 Anything I can do               1
123 nothing for now                 2
789 what is the issue               1
789 there is no issue now           2
789 thank you for contacting us     1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Just a note, in `R` concatenate (with `c()`) assembles the words into a vector (like a list or 1-D array in other languages), while `paste()` glues them together into a single string (which is what you're doing here)

Comment: Let's say the dataframe name is df. How would you concatenate while keeping ids per row. Note: I was able to concatenate words under each id to one paragraph, concatenating all the words under each id into one sencetence/paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach that also borrows `rleid` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L), 
               word = structure(c(8L, 9L, 2L, 21L, 7L, 16L, 21L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 6L, 15L, 20L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 18L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 6L, 4L, 19L), 
              .Label = c("Anything", "are", "can", "contacting", "do", "for", "good", "hi", "how", "I", "is", "issue", "no", "nothing", "now", "thank", "the", "there", "us", "what", "you"), class = "factor"), 
              spk = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))

df %>%
  mutate(spk_num = data.table::rleid(spk)) %>%
  mutate(word = as.character(word)) %>%
  group_by(id, spk, spk_num) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(words = map(data, unlist),
         words = map_chr(words, paste, collapse = " "))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
     id   spk spk_num data             words                      
  <int> <int>   <int> <list>           <chr>                      
1   123     1       1 <tibble [4 x 1]> hi how are you             
2   123     2       2 <tibble [3 x 1]> good thank you             
3   123     1       3 <tibble [4 x 1]> Anything I can do          
4   123     2       4 <tibble [3 x 1]> nothing for now            
5   789     1       5 <tibble [4 x 1]> what is the issue          
6   789     2       6 <tibble [5 x 1]> there is no issue now      
7   789     1       7 <tibble [5 x 1]> thank you for contacting us
```

Overview: First, make a `spk_num` column since your desired output wishes to differentiate between speakers within the same id. Next, `group_by` everything and `nest` the data. Finally we'll map `paste` with collapse across the whole output, but you'll first need to unlist the word data.

Comment: Tried the code above, but I got this: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `word` must be length 87 (the number of rows) or one, not 6

Comment: Make sure `word` is a not a factor. I've updated the code.

Comment: Still get the same: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `word` must be length 87 (the number of rows) or one, not 6.

Comment: Double check your spelling? Note, I've got `words` *not* `word` - I pasted the structure of the original `df` in my answer, it should be fully able to just copy-and-paste.

Comment: what's the data that you used in mutate(words = map(data, unlist)?

Comment: It's the result of the call to `nest()` -- run each section of the pipeline one at a time. That is remove each `%>%` to see what's going on after each successive pipe.

Comment: Thank you, Jason! Your code works. But, am still trying to figure out what each section does, especially the nest() and the last mutate.  Any details you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, .(word = paste(word, collapse = ' ')
     , id   = unique(id)
     , spk  = unique(spk))
   , by = .(phrase = rleid(spk))]

#    phrase                        word  id spk
# 1:      1              hi how are you 123   1
# 2:      2              good thank you 123   2
# 3:      3           Anything I can do 123   1
# 4:      4             nothing for now 123   2
# 5:      5           what is the issue 789   1
# 6:      6       there is no issue now 789   2
# 7:      7 thank you for contacting us 789   1
```

In tidyverse this is

```
df %>%
  mutate(phrase = data.table::rleid(spk)) %>%
  group_by(phrase) %>%
  summarise(id = unique(id),
            words = paste(word, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: I got this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , .(word = paste(word, collapse = " "),  :  unused argument (by = .(phrase = rleid("spk")))

Comment: You forgot to run `setDT(df)`

Comment: I used the tidyverse suggestion, but I got this:  Column `id` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Comment: Ran setDT(df), but I got this: Error in setDT(df) : 
  Can not convert 'df' to data.table by reference because binding is locked. It is very likely that 'df' resides within a package (or an environment) that is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings. Try copying the object to your current environment, ex: var <- copy(var) and then using setDT again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using data.table with the function paste() by grouping your rows appropriately. The only problem is that you have no reference of which phrase of the conversation you're on, so first you have to create a new column that specifies this.

```
library(data.table)

#This function takes a vector of speakers, say, (1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2) and gives you which phrase of the conversation you're on (1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)

class_phrase = function(spk){
  phrase = 1
  phrase_n = 1
  for(i in 2:length(spk)){
    if(spk[i] == spk[i-1])
      {phrase[i] = phrase[i-1]} else
      {phrase_n = phrase_n + 1
       phrase[i] = phrase_n}
  }
  return(phrase)
}

#Now you use this function with your data.table, grouping by id:

dt[, phrase := class_phrase(spk), by = id]

#Having a phrase number, you can just paste everything together by grouping your original data.table by id and phrase

dt[, .(word = paste(word, collapse = ' '), spk = unique(spk)), by = .(id, phrase)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr` approach, assuming your `word` column is a character vector:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(ifelse(df$spk != lag(df$spk, default = 0), 1, 0))) %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  mutate(sentence = paste(word, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-word, -group) %>%
  distinct() 

# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id   spk sentence                   
  <int> <int> <chr>                      
1   123     1 hi how are you             
2   123     2 good thank you             
3   123     1 Anything I can do          
4   123     2 nothing for now            
5   789     1 what is the issue          
6   789     2 there is no issue now      
7   789     1 thank you for contacting us
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base version:

```
df$i <-  cumsum(c(FALSE,!!diff(df$spk)))
aggregate(word ~ id + spk + i,df,paste,collapse= " ")[-3]
#    id spk                        word
# 1 123   1              hi how are you
# 2 123   2              good thank you
# 3 123   1           Anything I can do
# 4 123   2             nothing for now
# 5 789   1           what is the issue
# 6 789   2       there is no issue now
# 7 789   1 thank you for contacting us
```